# Effective polygon collision detection

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make so people would be able to pick up the coins I made a for loop to update every coin and every coin has a loop to check if any player is touching it so its like 250*25=6250 loops every tick/frame, any suggestion how to make it more effective ? so that my ping would not drop to 30 while playing on phone ?

Screen render code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++) {
    Coin coin = coins.get(i);
    coin.update(delta);
}
```

Coin update method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameScreen.players.size(); i++) {
    Player player = GameScreen.players.get(i);
    if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(polygon, player.getPolygon())) {
        //Picked up give coins blahblahblah
        break;
    }
}
```

coins.size is 250

and players.size is 25

Comment: This question might be a better fit (if not already answered) on [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bobulous it is within both. LibGDX is gamedev, yes. But it is also programming. This would be on-topic on both sites. (Unless it is a duplicate, but that is a different problem. The contents of the question is on-topic on both sites.)

Comment: @LunarWatcher Hence the reason I have not voted to close. But a question this closely related to game development could be expected to get a faster and more knowledgeable answer from the more specialised channel.

Comment: True. But on the other hand, there are more LibGDX questions here on SO than on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: The worst case scenario is that you have to check every player against every coin. There is absolutely no way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by making Spatial Grid detection.It reduced the amount of loops by ~40times.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with doing the check only from perspective of the players -- the coins don't need to check to see if anything is colliding with them unless there are other things besides players that interact with the coins. Depending on the shape of your players, it may work well just to have the player pick up all coins within a certain radius of the player's location -- if you want to do this, just find the distance from the player to each coin and pick up the coin if it's within that distance. (Actually it's more efficient to check distance squared -- the outcome is the same). If you don't want to use a radius for the pickup itself, it would still greatly reduce the amount of time it takes if you only test each player against coins that are within a distance where overlap is possible.